# Jquery binding key to body except a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress

I'm trying to bind a key to my entire page except to one class of elements.

```
$('*').not('.textarea-note').keypress(function (event) {
    // if key pressed is space
    if (event.which == 32) {
        alert('space pressed');
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

The problem is that I need to do the preventDefault() and when I'm in a textarea then I can't make a space caracter.

Am I doing something wrong or it's not possible to bind to everything except some class or something.

Thanks in advance !

Edit :

After the comment from Roland, I came up with this instead which is working perfectly.

```
$(document).keypress(function (event) {
    // if key pressed is space
    if (event.which == 32 && event.target.nodeName != "TEXTAREA") {
        if (videoPlaying) {
            pauseVideo();
        } else {
            playVideo();
        }
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: add the listener to your document then use event.target to check where the focus is

Comment: `I'm trying to bind a key to my entire page` Why that?  `The problem is that I need to do the preventDefault()` Why that? Really, looks like a XY problem

Comment: Any chance you can include a fiddle? And a bit of context as to why you'd want to do this?

Comment: I have a video that plays in the page and I need to push space to start/pause the video. But I have textareas on the page and when focused they need the space caracter. the preventDefault() is needed because if you are focused on the body and press space the page scroll down what I want to prevent.

Comment: The `.target` method is perfect for event delegation. Up vote for figuring that out.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for this...

```js
$(document).keypress(function(event) {
  // if key pressed is space
  if (event.which == 32) {



    if (event.target.id !== "a1") {// for class $(event.target).attr('class')
      alert('space pressed');
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="a1"></textarea>
<textarea id="a2"></textarea>
<textarea id="a3"></textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I edited my post with the change I made in my code and I use the event.target like you.

Comment: `.target` is best practice for event delegation

Comment: @dib 258 welcome if my answer is correct accept it as appreciation .