# HTML5 Video Player + Modal + Spacebar Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have am HTML5 Video Player on a page. Standard  tag...

```
<video id="player" controls crossorigin playsinline autoplay poster="poster.png" id="player" width="100%" height="auto">
    <!-- Video files -->
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4" style="max-width: 100px;"/>
    <!-- Fallback for browsers that don't support the <video> element -->
    <a href="video.mp4" download>Download</a>
</video>
```

I also have some jquery that enables pause/play when pressing the spacebar.

```
$(window).keypress(function(e) {
    var video = document.getElementById("player");
    if (e.which == 32) {
        if (video.paused)
            video.play();
        else
            video.pause();
            return false;
        }
});
```

This all works fine. But now I am adding a modal to the page using jquery-modal.js by Kyle Fox (http://github.com/kylefox/jquery-modal). The modal has a text input that may require the user to press the spacebar in order to enter more than one word. However, when the spacebar is pressed, instead of putting a space in the text input, it pauses/plays the video on the originating page.

My question is, how do I prevent the video from playing/pausing when the modal is displayed and instead work as intended to place a space between words?

Thanks, any help is appreciated.

Comment: My first thought would be to try to make sure the video does not have focus when the modal is displayed.

Comment: bind spacebar keypress to everything  except your text input or limit it to just your video: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33919244/2275490

Comment: You can include one more condition to check `input` box is focused or not. If it is focused, video play/pause function should not be called.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up getting it to work by altering the play/pause function on the originating page.

New function looks like this...

```
$(window).keypress(function(e) {
    var video = document.getElementById("player");
    if (e.which == 32 && event.target.id !== "name") {
        if (video.paused)
            video.play();
        else
            video.pause();
            return false;
        }
});
```

The code added was '&& event.target.id !== "name"'. The event.target.id refers to the text input with an id of name.

I added this just in case somebody stumbles upon this. Hopefully it helps.

Thanks to Vickel and Taplar for your responses.